# How do I invoke web services?

Tags: services

I am working on a site, and I want to integrate my site with an external site; for that, I need to use web services to get data from the external server. I don't know the technology used by the server.

I have to work as client. Can any one please tell me hoe to call web services from my site? Please write any code if it is required. Will `drupal_http_request()` help me?

I am using Drupal 6.

Answer (score 1):

You should have a look at the [Services](http://drupal.org/project/services) module. You can use XMLRPC and/or REST server (and many more) to communicate with your remote server. [Link to the documentation](http://drupal.org/node/109782).

> A standardized solution of integrating external applications with Drupal. Service callbacks may be used with multiple interfaces like REST, XMLRPC, JSON, [JSON-RPC](http://drupal.org/project/jsonrpc_server), [SOAP](http://drupal.org/project/soap_server), [AMF](http://drupal.org/project/amfphp), etc. This allows a Drupal site to provide web services via multiple interfaces while using the same callback code.

Comment: I had gone through services module, But I dont know how to use that for my purpose. Services module is used if we want to act as server, Am I right?

Comment: yes, you're right. But, that is not only what services can do. You can watch [services inside out](http://denver2012.drupal.org/program/sessions/services-inside-and-out).

Comment: Thankyou for sharing the link of video BTW I had seen it already. But still dont know what to do. Can you please tell me it step by step.

Answer (score 0):

The Alternate solution is Views . Install Views module and Json document Views module. With this you can get data from your site in many ways. Have a try